# wkhtmltopdf fails to respect page break with tables

Tags: css, webkit, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, page-break

It looks like wkhtmltopdf is a bit allergic to page breaks when dealing with tables given the number of questions and answers here in SO for different versions.

I am running the lastest version **0.12.6** at the time of writing.

This is my html code:

```html
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>A nice page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="printer.css" media="print" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="printer_friendly">
      <tbody class="printer_friendly_tbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="tbody_first" colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
          </th>
          <td>Random text</td>
          <td>Random text</td>
          <td>Random text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 0</td>
          <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 0</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody class="printer_friendly_tbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="tbody_first" colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
          </th>
          <td>Random text</td>
          <td>Random text</td>
          <td>Random text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 1</td>
          <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Following recommendation on SO, I have grouped rows that should stay together within a tbody and set for printing media the tbody property to:

```css
.printer_friendly_tbody {
    background-color:aliceblue;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-before:auto;
    page-break-after:auto;

}
```

I want to keep the tbody rows all together and if needed split the table before or after a .printer_friendly_tbody.

This is generating a perfect PDF when I use the print / pdf function of Chrome, but it fails when generating the pdf with wkhtmltopdf.

I have tried with both enable and disable print media option.

You may wonder, why I am insisting with wkhtmltopdf, the reason is that I would like to use other features of wkhtmltopdf.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution, or if it is not really a solution it is at least a workaround.

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/abulgher/8ab134d3b7889b8bd4384ffa0c3db0d8) and for the snippet below.

It is producing pdf with page breaks at the required position with both wkhtmltopdf and the PDF printing option of Chrome.

```css
.printer_friendly {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-before: auto;
  page-break-after: auto;
  border: 4px;
  border-block-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table.printer_friendly {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.printer_friendly tr:first-of-type {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: larger;
  color: red;
  border-style: none;
}

.printer_friendly tr:first-of-type th {
  border-style: none;
}

.printer_friendly th {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.printer_friendly td,
th {
  border: 1px;
  border-block-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<HTML>

<head>
  <title>A nice page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="printer.css" media="print" />
</head>

<body>
  <div> It works with PDF printing of Chrome and with WKHTMLTOPDF if I have the following structure:
    <pre>
                    &lt;table class="printer_friendly"&gt;
                      &lt;tr&gt;
                        &lt;th colspan="6"&gt;This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 13&lt;/th&gt;
                      &lt;/tr&gt;
                      &lt;tr&gt;
                        &lt;th colspan="3.0" rowspan="5"&gt;
                          &lt;img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" /&gt;
                        &lt;/th&gt;
                        &lt;th&gt;Random text&lt;/th&gt;
                        &lt;th&gt;Random text&lt;/th&gt;
                        &lt;th&gt;Random text&lt;/th&gt;
                      &lt;/tr&gt;
                      &lt;tr&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (0, 0) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (0, 1) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (0, 2) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                      &lt;/tr&gt;
                      &lt;tr&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (1, 0) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (1, 1) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                        &lt;td&gt;This is (1, 2) in tbody 13&lt;/td&gt;
                      &lt;/tr&gt;
                    &lt;/table&gt;
                    </pre> and the following css for print media
    <pre>
                    .printer_friendly {
                        page-break-inside:avoid;
                        page-break-before:auto;
                        page-break-after:auto;
                    }</pre>
  </div>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 0</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 0</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 1</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 2</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 3</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 4</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 5</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 6</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 7</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 8</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 9</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 10</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 10</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 10</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 11</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 11</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 11</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 12</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 12</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 12</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="printer_friendly">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">This is the beginning of a new picture. This must be the first in the groupof tbody 13</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3.0" rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/pdf_download.png" width="300px" />
      </td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
      <td>Random text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (0, 0) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (0, 1) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (0, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (1, 0) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (1, 1) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (1, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (2, 0) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (2, 1) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (2, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is (3, 0) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (3, 1) in tbody 13</td>
      <td>This is (3, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (0, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6">This is (1, 2) in tbody 13</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</HTML>
```

I hope it may be of help for someone!